# django model form edit automatically

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a little question :) 
I want to add/edit user directly with django model. I did that :

```
class AddClientView(generic.FormView):
success_url = 'manager/liste'
form_class = AddClientForm
template_name = 'Manager/Clients/formClient.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    retour = super(AddClientView, self).get_context_data()
    retour['forms'] = AddClientForm

    return retour

def form_valid(self, form):
    retour = super(AddClientView, self).form_valid(form)
    form.save()

    return retour


class EditClientView(generic.FormView):
success_url = '/manager/liste'
form_class = AddClientForm
template_name = 'Manager/Clients/formClient.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    retour = super(EditClientView, self).get_context_data()
    client = Clients.objects.get(id=self.kwargs["client"])
    retour['forms'] = AddClientForm(instance=client)
    retour['client'] = client
    return retour

def form_valid(self, form):
    retour = super(EditClientView, self).form_valid(form)
    a = Clients.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['client'])
    a.prenom = form.cleaned_data['prenom']
    a.nom = form.cleaned_data['nom']
    a.telephone = form.cleaned_data['telephone']
    a.mail = form.cleaned_data['mail']
    a.adresse = form.cleaned_data['adresse']
    a.date_anniversaire = form.cleaned_data['date_anniversaire']

    a.save()

    for pConseomme in form.cleaned_data['pConsomme']:
        a.pConsomme.add(pConseomme)

    for pInteret in form.cleaned_data['pInteret']:
        a.pInteret.add(pInteret)

    return retour
```

For edit, i want to do the same as add, like that : 
just a

```
form.save()
```

But it does not work ... it creates a new user. How i can do that ? 
Thanks guys !

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same for the edit but consider adding a new user and updating a user is not the same thing. When you add it creates a new user but when you edit you should first find the specific user and change its data and later you can save the model.

```
user= get_object_or_404(User, pk=form.cleaned_data['user'].pk)
```

You can youse `get_object_or_404()` to find the user according to its **pk** and the do the same procedure you did on add.